# Encoding Issue Title Tag

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, diacritics, htmlspecialchars

I've got a little problem with the  tag in combination with PHP. My code is:

```
$title = '....';
echo '<title>'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</title>';
```

When i use `"Niederländische Zitate"` the browser outputs "Niederl�ndische Zitate"
When i use `"Niederl&auml;ndische Zitate"` the browser outputs "Niederländische Zitate"

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What precisely is the difference between your two inputs?  When SO renders your question, both are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to meta tag, you also need to:

**a)**  send UTF-8 `header` like this:

```
 header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in the very beginning of your script.

**b)**  and save the script file as `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding. Use any good code editor, like Notepad++ which allows this.